# WebView goBack() восстановить состояние скролла

Tags: android, android-sdk

На начальной странице `WebView` двигаю скролл вниз, далее кликаю по ссылке и загружается новая страница в `WebView`. Затем программно вызываю метод `goBack()`, который из кеша загружает предыдущую страницу. Но положение скролла предыдущей страницы не восстанавливается.
Можно ли каким-нибудь образом это исправить?